# Additional 0 in varbinary insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, varbinary

I have a problem when I am trying to move a varbinary(max) field from one DB to another.
If I insert like this:
0xD0CF11E0A1B11AE10000000
It results the beginning with an additional '0':
0x0D0CF11E0A1B11AE10000000

And I cannot get rid of this. I've tried many tools, like SSMS export tool or BCP, but without any success. And it would be better fro me to solve it in a script anyway.

And don't have much kowledge about varbinary (a program generates it), my only goal is to copy it:)

Comment: Invalid literal....Odd number of hex digits - must be even.

Comment: Each character in hexadecimal notation represents a nibble. Varbinary works in terms of bytes. Your first expression contains 23 hex characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
0xD0CF11E0A1B11AE10000000
```

This value contains an odd number of characters. Varbinary stores bytes. Each byte is represented by *exactly two* hexadecimal characters. You're either missing a character, or your not storing bytes.

Here, SQL Server is guessing that the most significant digit is a zero, which would not change the numeric value of the string. For example:

```
select 0xD0C "value"
    ,cast(0xD0C as int) "as_integer"
    ,cast(0x0D0C as int) "leading_zero"
    ,cast(0xD0C0 as int) "trailing_zero"


 value       3_char     leading_zero     trailing_zero    
 ----------  ---------  ---------------  ---------------- 
 0d0c        3340       3340             53440
```

Or:

```
select 1 "test"
where 0xD0C = 0x0D0C

 test    
 ------- 
 1
```

It's just a difference of SQL Server assuming that varbinary always represents bytes.

Comment: Yes you are right, this solves the problem. The weird thing is, my original varbinary field contains odd number of characters as well...(that's why I tried to copy that). Any idea how it is possible?

Comment: Two more zero did the job! Thanks;)

Comment: @landonhand115 It depends entirely on how your systems are choosing to represent the value. An *arbitrary hexadecimal number* for example, can certainly have an odd number of digits. It's just that SQL Server says that hex values are interpreted as bytes.

Comment: @landonhand115 Two zeroes?